# Measure memory usage of a distributed application

Tags: c++, linux, performance, memory, distributed-computing

What is the best way to measure memory usage of a distributed application?

I'm not sure if using `ps` on each machine is the best approach on this problem -- the saner the solution, the better (:

P.S.: The application is in `c++`, and is to be executed using `linux`.

Comment: What's wrong with ps on each machine?

Comment: @inetknght I just was not very comfortable with the fact of having to parse the whole thing, hither and thither; I was just looking for something a bit more *saner/easier*. Another possibility would be `free -m`, with some interval; but I would be retrieving the memory usage for the entire machine, and not only for some selected processes. I can't think of any better than `ps`, after all.

Comment: The sanest way is to have the application running under the control of a Distributed Resource Manager like Sun Grid Engine, Torque, LSF, LoadLeveler, SLURM, etc. These come with built-in resource usage meters that can aggregate the metrics for each process in a distributed job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install one of several really good open source enterprise datacenter monitoring tools. Good ones are:

- [Hyperic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hyperic-hq/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

These are terribly easy to install and give you not only memory but also any other system property you could shake a stick at.

Answer (score 3):

To get memory usage programmatically, read from `/proc/self/statm`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::ifstream statm("/proc/self/statm");
        size_t mem_virt, mem_rss, mem_shared;
        statm >> mem_virt >> mem_rss >> mem_shared;
        std::cout << "Memory stats:" << std::endl <<
                     "Virtual memory size:  " << mem_virt   << std::endl <<
                     "Resident memory size: " << mem_rss    << std::endl <<
                     "Shared memory size:   " << mem_shared << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I guess you mostly interested in *resident memory size*, that is, how much RAM is accessible to the program right now. See [an answer from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/48582/how-is-memory-usage-reported-in-linux/48610#48610) which describes the meaning of these three types.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to implement simple logic in separate thread of your application. That will sleep most of time, wake up once in couple of minutes, call [mallinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) and put that data to log or network.

Answer (score 0):

There's a memory checker app called alleyoop (which uses the valgrind lib) that can monitor a program. I recommend checking this out: http://alleyoop.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cat /proc/PROC_PID/smaps
```

in order to get the detail of all the memory pages used by your process. However, you don't have the indication whether the memory is really used or just reserved. There is also

```
pmap -x PROC_ID, doing similar work.
```

Finally, there is

```
cat/proc/PROC_ID/status | grep Vm
```

giving you informations about all memory types used by your program.